# JSF 2.0 stability issues

Tags: jsf-2, jsf-1.2, stability

Recently we are planning to migrate from JSF1.2 to JSF2.0.Our web application uses RF3.3 and deployed on JBoss Server.

However over few months I have heard JSF2.0 is not stable and still JSF 1.2 is preferable provided you dont have any such urgency to migrate to facelets.

We use JSF1.2 extensively in our application and as on date there's no such requirement which can be fulfilled only by using JSF2.0.Hence I want to know is it wise to stick with JSF1.2 or migrate to JSF2.0...

Also kindly point out the stability issues of JSF2.0 over JSF1.2
Tried searching on net but with no success...

People who are using JSF2.0 will be the best one to guide me with the compatibility issues of JSF2.0 and stability issues...Kindly throw some light...

Answer (score 0):

the detailed information about this is given by [BalusC in his answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0)

following is the Painfulness of upgrading JSF 1.2 to 2.0 depends on the view technology which you are currently using and which you want to use.

> JSP 2.x to JSP 2.x = Almost no effort.
>
> Facelets 1.x to Facelets 2.0 = Little effort.
>
> JSP 2.x to Facelets 2.0 = Lot of effort. Double this if you also have custom components.

Comment: I am looking more towards the stability issues of JSf2.0 over JSF 1.2...What are the stability issues of JSF2.0....

Comment: have you gone through the answer of BalusC ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4441713/migrating-from-jsf-1-2-to-jsf-2-0

Comment: @Hukamanata We are using JSF2.0 in several projects for nearly 2 years and stability has never been an issue. There were some bugs, especially in the early versions of Mojarra implementations but as far as I know none of them affected overall stability.

Comment: @Hemant Metalia Yes before posting this question I had read that post around 2-3 times...However I was unable to find an answer for my question hence a new post....